# How to remove extension .php in subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have problem to remove extension .php. For example the url is like
https://www.domainname.net/dev/member.php. I just want to remove the extension .php. can someone help me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your htaccess :

```
 Options +Multiviews
```

then you will be able to access your file without extension.

Comment: Sometimes people just don't realize there are other ways that can accomplish the same task without a rewrite. Unfortunately content-negotiation seems rarely used.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the .htaccess code snippet that will help you put this code in your .htaccess file:

```
# Apache Rewrite Rules
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

# Remove .php-extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php 

# End of Apache Rewrite Rules
 </IfModule>
```